# undefined reference due to ubuntu's library linking mechanism

Tags: c++, ubuntu

My data analysis program (based on C++) is working fine on OpenSUSE. But when I use it in my Laptop running Ubuntu 12.04. It shows following error:

```
ent$ make
g++ -g -o FBBA FBBA.o  libFBBAnal.so  -L../FBRun libFBRun.so\
    -L/usr/local/root/lib -lRint -L/usr/local/root/lib -lGui -lCore -lCint -lRIO -lNet -lHist -lGraf -lGraf3d -lGpad -lTree -lRint -lPostscript -lMatrix -lPhysics -lMathCore -lThread -pthread -lm -ldl -rdynamic -m64 -L/usr/local/root/lib -lCore -lCint -lRIO -lNet -lHist -lGraf -lGraf3d -lGpad -lTree -lRint -lPostscript -lMatrix -lPhysics -lMathCore -lThread -pthread -lm -ldl -rdynamic -lGpad -lHist -lGraf -lGraf3d -lTree -lRint -lPostscript -lMatrix -lPhysics -lMathCore -lRIO -lNet -lThread -lCore -lCint -pthread -lm -ldl -rdynamic  -lTMVA -lMinuit -lXMLIO -lMLP -lTreePlayer -L/usr/lib64/ -lstdc++
libFBBAnal.so: undefined reference to `TCanvas::TCanvas(char const*, char const*, int, int, int, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [FBBA] Error 1er code here
```

My research on internet shows that this could be solved by changing the order of libraries in the command line (before module). But I have a Makefile where all these commands are shown. And I am not good at coding. help please !

Comment: You don't usually link with *.so files at link-time (they're usually the equivalent of Windows *.dlls). Those are normally loaded at runtime. You link to a *.lib (or sometimes *.a) that contains the stubs of the functions that are contained in the *.so. Or you link it completely at runtime.

Comment: So change the Makefile.

Comment: @PeterT I am not using windows, I am using Ubuntu. and user31... if I knew how to change Makefile, I wouldn't ask here !

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it was issue of Ubuntu's library linking as it was expected. I had to manually put the libraries at the end of the line where the error was appearing. !